# Why causes the length of the array to be printed at the end of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I have a JavaFX textField from which I am getting a string input. I'm using the toCharArray() to pass the string as an array of chars. But for some unexplained reason, the length of array appears after the array. Any ideas what might be causing that? I expect the input to be 16 elements, so I'm hard coding it but for some reason the result that I get is 18 elements with last two elements being 1, 6. (When I change the input length, the last two elements follow). Now I know what calling it a bug in Java is foolish, hence the problem is on my end, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out?

```
public class something extends Application {
    String input;
    char[] chars;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField field = new TextField("Enter");
    input = field.getText();

    Button btn = new Button("Check");
    btn.setOnAction(e -> validator(input));
}

 public void validator(String input) {

    chars = new char[input.length()];

    System.out.println(input.length()); // this still shows 16

    if (chars.length == 16) {
    chars = input.toCharArray();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        System.out.print(chars[i]);
    } //here the problem occurs, when I try to print the array

    System.out.println(chars.length); //this also shows 16

    if (chars[0] == '4'){
           System.out.println("yayy");
           check(input);
        }
    else {
      // shows an alert
    }
}
}

public void check(String str){
  // some other code that works properly
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Please break down the code to a [MCVE]. Method [`String#toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) does not append anything to the returned array.

Comment: In Java, Lists will automatically add to their size when they are filled and you try to add more elements, arrays stay the same length. Once full, they're full. You are not appending anything to your array, you are overwriting it, assigning a reference to a new array to the reference variable

Comment: @Stultuske - This is not about lists.

Comment: @StephenC I know, read the rest of my comment and you'll see that

Comment: Yes ... but why even bring up lists at all?   How does it help the OP understand what is *actually* going on here?

Comment: @Turing85 is this not compact enough? because I have already stripped away a lot of the unimportant code, I can try to do it more I guess

Comment: @Abby you could have stripped all GUI-related parts.

Comment: @StephenC first, I mention the/a type that has the behavior described, then, I explain the difference with the type the OP uses, and then I explain why she gets an 'unexpected' result.

Comment: `if (chars[0] == 4){` I'm pretty sure this yields the wrong result. You should compare to a char, if you want to check for the digit `4` in the string: `if (chars[0] == '4'){`, since `'a' == 52`

Comment: thank you very much!! @fabian you saved me hours of debugging and headache :joy:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that every char is printed with `print`, not `println`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    System.out.print(chars[i]);
}
System.out.println(); // To a new line
System.out.println(chars.length); //this also shows 16
```

Comment: thanks... i feel so stupid now :(  i haven't done programming in a while so maybe that's why this slipped my mind

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java does not append the length of an array to an array.  And neither does `String.toCharArray`.  So, whatever you are seeing, that is NOT the explanation.

On the other hand, I can't explain what *exactly* is happening because you haven't provided us with the actual inputs and outputs.

---

Even so, there are some clear misconceptions evident from your code

Firstly, this statement doesn't do anything useful:

```
chars = new char[input.length()];
```

Why?  Because

```
chars = input.toCharArray();
```

is going to return a brand new array.  It does NOT fill the character array you allocated previously.  (The assignment just replaces it ...)

A second misconception is this in this:

```
if (chars[0] == 4){
     ....
}
```

It is not clear what what you are expecting the test to do, but it is NOT testing for the character '4'.  It is testing for the Unicode code-point \u0004 ... which is the ASCII `EOT` control character, or `CNTRL-D` on a typical western keyboard.

In short, the validation is *probably* not testing what you are expecting.  (Why would you expect the user to enter a control character?)

To test for the character '4' ... use a character literal.  Single quotes.

```
if (chars[0] == '4'){
     ....
}
```

Comment: oh thank you very much.. this was another issue with my code that I wasn't able to explain but I was gonna come to it after I had solved the problem with the array (which I have now thanks to Joop Eggen). as I explained to Joop as well, I've out of the programming game for a while but I think it makes sense now as I realize that i should add the quotes around it.